# Indicate external value on matplotlib colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have a scatterplot that is coloured with respect to a third variable. I can create a colorbar for this plot, but would like to also indicate an external level (just with a horizontal line) on the colorbar.

```
X = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
Y = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
Z = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.scatter(X, Y, c=Z, cmap='gist_heat', vmin=Z.min(), vmax=Z.max(), s=500)
cbar = plt.colorbar()
```

I would like a green (say) line to appear at 4.0 on the colourbar. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colorbar is an axis.  You can plot a horizontal line on it.  To find out where to plot the line, use the colorbar's norm to map your "special" value to its position on the colorbar axis:

```
cbar.ax.hlines(cbar.norm(4), 0, 1, color='green')
```